# laravel php foreach use if div open and close

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

there is a different structure to show projects
Project 1 and 2 are in the same  Project 3 is in a different 
Project 4 and 5 are in the same  Project 6 is in a different 
it goes on like this

div will open if $i == 1

If $i == 2 the div will be closed

If $i == 3 the div will be opened and closed

my code

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    @if($loop->iteration % 3 === 0 || $loop->first || $loop->iteration % 2 === 0)
        <div class="project"> @endif

            <img src="{{ Voyager::image($project->image) }}" alt="{{ $project->title }}">

            @if($loop->iteration % 3 === 0 || $loop->last || $loop->iteration % 2 === 0) </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

my code result

```
        <div class="project">
        <img src="project1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img src="project5.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project6.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img src="project7.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project8.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <img src="project9.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
```

the result i want

```
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="project2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="project5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project7.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="project8.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img src="project9.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem a little more clearly. What is not working as you expect in your current code?

Comment: @JimmieJohansson I hope I can explain now

Answer (score 2):

You can chunk the collection to two and one items in it respectively:

```
@foreach ($projects
    ->chunk(3)
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->chunk(2);
    })
    ->flatten(1) as $projectData)
    <div class="project">
        @foreach ($projectData as $project)
            <img src="{{ Voyager::image($project->image) }}" alt="{{ $project->title }}">
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
@if($loop->first)
    <div class="project"> @endif
        

        @if($loop->iteration % 3 === 0) </div>
<div class="project">
        @endif
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($project->image) }}" alt="{{ $project->title }}">
@if($loop->iteration % 3 === 0) </div>
<div class="project">

@endif
@if($loop->last)
    </div> 
@endif
@endforeach
```